# Bus error with little remaining disk space and a Python program

Tags: python, linux, bus-error

Several times I was getting "bus error" when trying to run Python with CPython (2.7, x64, RHEL) in a peculiar situation of very little disk space remaining.

This resulted in some of the `.pyc` files being damaged (I checked their MD5 checksum against MD5 of `.pyc` files when the program is working as usual) and trying to run the Python program resulted in "bus error" over and over again.

Freeing a good deal of diskspace and deleting all the `.pyc` files reliably solved the problem (i.e. the same program was running correctly).

My question is *why* that "bus error" happened in such conditions?